# I want to make two cloned rangens not produce the same results

Tags: java

I made a a line of code that generates a Feat. I added a Feat2 but i want it to not repeat. here's the code

```
System.out.println("Feat 1:");

    String[] Tasks6 = {"Actor", "Athlete", "Dragon Hide", "Dual Wielder", "Durable", "Elven Accuracy", "Firearm Specialist", "Healer", "Heavily Armored", "Martial Adept", "Mobile", "Moderately Armored", "Mounted Combatant", "Resilient", "Ritual Caster", "Ambidextrous", "Shield Master"};

    int Feat1 = (int) (Math.random() * (16)); // Random number generator
    System.out.println(Tasks6[Feat1]); // Task printer

    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("Feat 2:");

    String[] Tasks7 = {"Actor", "Athlete", "Dragon Hide", "Dual Wielder", "Durable", "Elven Accuracy", "Firearm Specialist", "Healer", "Heavily Armored", "Martial Adept", "Mobile", "Moderately Armored", "Mounted Combatant", "Resilient", "Ritual Caster", "Ambidextrous", "Shield Master"};

    int Feat2 = (int) (Math.random() * (16)); // Random number generator
    System.out.println(Tasks7[Feat2]); // Task printer

    System.out.println("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.
Corrected the capitalization to fit Java standards. Methods and variables should be camelCased.
If tasks6 is always going to be the same as tasks 7, then you can omit the redundancy.
Created a method to return a random number like how you had. Instead of hard coding '16', I used task.legnth to programmatically fetch the value.
And lastly, I'm using a while loop to generate random numbers, if the two values match than it'll generate new numbers until they don't. This will guarantee feat 1 and 2 will be differnt.

```
    String[] tasks6 = {"Actor", "Athlete", "Dragon Hide", "Dual Wielder", "Durable", "Elven Accuracy", "Firearm Specialist", "Healer", "Heavily Armored", "Martial Adept", "Mobile", "Moderately Armored", "Mounted Combatant", "Resilient", "Ritual Caster", "Ambidextrous", "Shield Master"};

    int feat1 = 0;
    int feat2 = 0;

    while (feat1 == feat2) {
        feat1 = getRandomNumber(tasks6.length);
        feat2 = getRandomNumber(tasks6.length);
    }
    System.out.println("Feat 1:");

    System.out.println(tasks6[feat1]); // Task printer

    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("Feat 2:");
    
    System.out.println(tasks6[feat2]); // Task printer

    System.out.println("\n");
}

static int getRandomNumber(int max) {
    return (int) (Math.random() * (max));
}
```